# CSS Specficity in XUL

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul

There's a default style sheet which has:

```
toolbarbutton {
  -moz-appearance: toolbarbutton;
}
```

[image]

now i want to change thatappearnce is none lik this:

```
.profilist-tbb {
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

[image]

this is the element:

```
<toolbarbutton class="profilist-tbb"></toolbarbutton>
```

however the computed style, (and when i hover over it, it is obvious) the -moz-apperance is toolbarbutton which follows the default style sheet.
[image]

however my classses backgroundColor just won't take.

the css specficity is that class is higher than element. if you apply this in html it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/c5hr1579/

how to make my class be more specific? even if i set id of my toolbarbutton to `profilist-tbb` and change stylesheet to `#profilist-tbb{` it doesnt take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you most likely use `nsIDOMWindowUtils.loadSheet` (or the style sheet service), you should load the sheet as `Ci.nsIDOMWindowUtils.AUTHOR_SHEET`, so that the sheets are placed in the correct position within the cascade.

Right now, you appear to be using `USER_SHEET`. That will cause the sheet to be inserted before any author sheets, including `chrome://global/skin/toolbarbutton.css` (which is an author sheet), which then resets your `-moz-appearance` again.

Comment: Oh my gosh this makes sense!!! I didn't test but I'm sure it works thanks man!!! I never understood diff between author and user sheets till now.